# Inequality in a Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is it true that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\le c\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\;,\quad\quad \text{for all}\quad u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)?$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_inequality

Comment: @Xander Henderson, there the inequality is written in the link in a bounded domain. Is it true in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: Related: http://matjohn.faculty.ku.edu/Teaching/S20/poincare.pdf

Answer (score 1):

So this is called the Poincaré inequality. It is true on a bounded domain. When you are in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and not in a bounded domain, you need some additional weights (for example it works with Gaussian weights, or sufficiently decaying weights).

In the form you are asking, it is false. indeed, take $\langle x\rangle = \sqrt{1+|x|^2}$ and
$$
u(x) = \frac{1}{\langle x\rangle}
$$
Then $u∉ L^2$ (since $u^2 ∼ |x|^{-2}$ when $x\to\infty$), but
$$
∇u  = \frac{-x}{\langle x\rangle^3}
$$
therefore $∇u ∈ L^2$ since $|∇u|^2 = \frac{|x|^2}{\langle x\rangle^6} ∼ |x|^{-4}$ when $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

No

$u=1|_{ [0,1]^2} $ indicatrice function of $ [0,1] ^2$
$u\in H^2(R^2)$

$\nabla u=0$, but $u $ no zero

Comment: There may be a problem here insofar as the true/distributional gradient of that function is not at all $0$...

Comment: Yeah, there are two Dirac delta hiding there ...

Comment: Also this would also be a counterexample for bounded domains, which is true